# Variable name in Freemarker Template Language

Tags: java, freemarker

How to set a variable name like

```
1. "var(a)" in interpolation like ${var(a)}
2."var/a" in interpolation like ${var/a}
are these valid variable names? or whats the alternate.
```

Comment: There are no restrictions regarding characters in variable names, but using them is verbose if you have reserved characters like `(`, `)`, and `/` in them. Also I'm not sure if it's clear, but `${var/a}` means "take the value of variable `var`, and divide it with the value of variable `a`, and print the result".

Answer (score 0):

The best solution here would be to have a meaningful variable name instead of using reserved characters. You can use the variable down the line by using `${variablename}`

Answer (score 0):

It's an old issue but I think it can be helpful so i'll answer it anyway:

First of all its really important to note that **those names are not a good practice on variable naming**, not only in freemarker but in most languages. And for that reason the best thing to do in a situation like that would be **rethinking the variable name**.

Please try your best to give each variable a proper name. This is something that may not seems so important a first but as you get more experienced in programming you will increasingly realize how that can make a huge diference.

I'm sorry for this big 'unrelated' explanation before the answer, but the objective here is to make an addition to the community, so that is very important to clarify as this feature can be very misused.

But anyway, if you have a very specific situation where you need to use an unusual variable name with unusual characters you can do it by using a string literal as the name of the variable when using the **#assign** directive. [Oficial reference](https://freemarker.apache.org/docs/ref_directive_assign.html)

But there is a catch: when you create such an unusual name for a variable, it may be  a confusing name to call (in a interpolation for example). So when you need the content of the variable you can't simply call its name, you must use  the special variable **.vars**. [Oficial reference](https://freemarker.apache.org/docs/ref_specvar.html)

An example where you set the variable for the first time, then write it, then change it and write it again would be like:

```
<#assign "var(a)" = "FIRST TIME" />
${.vars["var(a)"]}
<#assign "var(a)" = "SECOND TIME" />
${.vars["var(a)"]}
```

*A common mistake is to try to use <#assign .vars["myOddv@rName"] = "content" />
but that will not work.